# Написать запрос аналогичный wherePivotNull()/wherePivotNotNull()

Tags: laravel, laravel4

Использую laravel 4.2, есть необходимость сделать запрос вида

```
$model->relation()->wherePivot('param', '=', 'NULL');
```

или

```
$model->relation()->wherePivot('param', '!=', 'NULL');
```

Но **такая версия запроса не подходит**, так как во-первых для получения полей со значением NULL используется не

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE param = NULL
```

a

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE param IS NULL
```

Во-вторых по неизвестной причине **работают запросы только в таком виде**

```
$model->relation()->wherePivot('param', '=', null);  
$model->relation()->wherePivot('param', '!=', 'NULL');
```

- не одинаково и неочевидно.

Для `where` запроса в laravel есть методы `whereNull` и `whereNotNull`.
Какой посоветуете красивый способ замены недостающих методов `wherePivotNull` и `wherePivotNotNull` или может быть способы расширить стандартный класс?

Answer (score 0):

В Laravel это называется Query Scope добавляется так:

```
class SomeClass extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query Обязательный параметр
     */
    public function scopeWherePivot($query, $column, $operator, $value)
    {
        return $query->...;
    }

}
```

Почитать можно тут: [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Кажется вы не правильно поняли вопрос. Pivot это не поле из таблицы, это параметры из связи моделей Many-To-Many и никакого отношения к scope не имеют: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: Я знаю, что это за таблица. К какому результату должен привести вызов ``$model->wherePivot('param', '=', 'NULL');``?

Comment: Вернуть Builder с моделями, для которых дополнительное поле 'param' в указанной связи many-to-many имеет значение null

Comment: Какие это должны быть модели? Вы пишете ``$model->wherePivot..``, но у модели может быть несколько связей many-to-many да и сам метод ``wherePivot()`` присутствует только у ``BelongsToMany`` связи.

Comment: поправила пример чтобы было понятнее